# What is the best approach to having a web site and web application with the same domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, multi-tenant

I am writing a web application using Google App Engine, and to promote it (and give more information about it), I will also have a web site.  For ease of deployments, it makes sense to have the web site separate from the application itself.  I would like to be able to make changes to the web site independent of the application.  I would think that making a change to the web site would NOT mean a re-deployment of the application.

I would like to have a domain, and for the purpose of this question, let's call it www.example.com.

App Engine allows for multi-tenancy, and it makes sense to use sub-domains.  For this question, let's assume www.org1.example.com / www.org2.example.com, etc.

Given this scenario, how is this done in the enterprise world on GAE?  Do companies:

1. have the web site and application all as one?
2. use their hosting provider to redirect sub-domain requests to their application?
3. have completely separate domains for the web site and application?
4. something else?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to independently deploy the web app and the web site they need to be at least in separate GAE services/modules, which offer [complete code isolation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#service_isolation).

Yes, it's not a problem to have the separate services mapped under different subdomains of the same domain. I'm not very sure if it'd work with the sub-domain split you proposed and with wildcard SSL certificates. From [App Engine support for SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#app_engine_support_for_ssl_certificates):

> Wildcard certificates only support one level of subdomain.

So I didn't even try such subdomains. But I am using a wildcard certificate like `*.example.com` with subdomains like these, each mapped to a different service:

```
www-org1.example.com
www-org2.example.com
```

I'm also using a [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref) file to route each domain to the respective service.

Now about the multi-tenancy, I'm unsure if it's what you actually need, because it's offering just data isolation, not code isolation. You still need to address code isolation if you want to deploy them independently. From [About multitenancy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/multitenancy/#Python_About_multitenancy):

> *Multitenancy* is the name given to a software architecture in which one instance of an application, running on a remote server, serves
>   many client organizations (also known as tenants).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @dan-cornilescu.  Just to be clear, what I am looking for is a static web site (i.e. www.example.com) to provide general info, and will be a separate code base (and deployment) from the application.  The application will be all subdomains (*.example.com).

Comment: IMO, this scenario is a typical one, so I'm asking what the approach is that most companies take? Do they have one application including the static site, and redeploy everything all at once, or do they split using subdomains, or is there another approach?

Comment: Donno about others, but for my apps and services - each service has its own subdomain and all share the same wildcard certificate.